# Alterando Width do component Drawer material-ui react

Tags: react

Estou aprendendo tanto react quanto a utilizar o material-ui em conjunto com react, meu problema é que eu gostaria de utilizar um "custom width" para o componente [Drawer](https://material-ui.com/demos/drawers/), na minha tentativa inicial eu fiz o seguinte:

```
<Drawer variant="permanent" style={{width:'240px'}}>
  <div>
    <IconButton>
      <HomeIcon />
      <Typography color="inherit" noWrap>
        Início
      </Typography>
    </IconButton>
   </div>
  <Divider />
</Drawer>
```

Contudo, o resultado obtido é o seguinte:

[image: drawer imagem]

Percebi com isso que o Drawer é composto por duas "div", quando eu utilizo a tag style, apenas a primeira div recebe o estilo desejado, e modificando manualmente o CSS no console do navegador da segunda div, eu obtenho o resultado desejado:

[image: drawer resultado esperado]

Vou ressaltar novamente que sou novo tanto em react quanto na utilização do pacote material-ui. Então o que eu devo fazer para alcançar essa "segunda div", gostaria muito de entender o que eu estou fazendo de errado.

Comment: Boa noite, o problema que você esta definido o width no `Drawer `, o correto é você definir o tamanho no conteúdo dele, defina o width na `<div style={{width:'240px'}}>` de dentro e remova do `Drawer`, no site do material-ui a varias [exemplos](https://codesandbox.io/s/yv98v8vwr1) de utilização e é possivel ver bem com é definido as medidas.

Comment: obrigado pela resposta, eu havia feito dessa forma, mas pensei que devido as minhas limitações ao conhecimento em ambas as ferramentas react e material-ui essa forma não estaria correta de se trabalhar, alias obrigado pelo exemplo. Ele me ajudou com algumas duvidas também

Comment: A sim tranquilo também de uma olhada em overrides no material ui, demonstra como sobrescrever o css padrão dos elementos é bem interessante.